# Ionice on cp - why I need set dir

Tags: linux, nice, ionice

I'm wondering why I can't set ionice for cp.

```
 ionice -c2 -n0 cp
```

I run this command and I get:

```
 cp: missing file argument 
 Try `cp --help' for more information
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to change the ionice level for all subsequent calls to `cp`. If so, you are misunderstanding the way `ionice` works (and `nice`, for that matter).

The `ionice` command refers to a **process**, not to a binary. You can use it either to change the ionice level of a currently running process, by giving it the PID as an argument, or you can use it when you start a process.

So, either you keep watch on the machine and manually set a new `ionice` level for the problematic processes, like this:

```
 ionice -c2 -n0 -p 12345 # replace 12345 with the PID you want to act nicer
```

or you change the scripts you're working with so that they use `ionice -c2 -n0 cp from to` instead of just `cp from to`.

There's still no guarantee that things will get better. IO is more complicated than you might think, and especially so if you're working with virtual machines.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `cp` command, you have to specify the file(s) you wish to copy. 
You didn't do that here, so the `cp` command is giving you an error.

Comment: Following that topic: http://serverfault.com/questions/328050/nice-with-cp-for-giving-more-processor-priority-on-cp
Is there any way to set ionice for cp for whole system?

Comment: You could possibly alias "cp" to "ionice -c2 -n0 cp", but I don't think that's a reasonable thing to do. Are you having a performance problem. ionice is not a great method to fix performance issues... What's the real problem?

Comment: During some tests, system is copying some large file. IO increase and tests are failed in general. I need to change priorities in Io operations..